# Is using deployments to isolate clients in Kubernetes a good idea?

Tags: kubernetes, architecture, containers, google-kubernetes-engine

We’re in the process of migrating our aging monolith to a more robust solution and landed on Kubernetes as the most appropriate platform to achieve what we’re looking for. At the same time, we’re looking to split out and isolate our client data for security and improved privacy.

What we’re considering is ultimately having one database per customer, and embedding those connection details into a deployment for each of them. We’d then build a routing service of some kind that would link a client’s request to their respective deployment/service.

Because our individual clients vary wildly in size (we have some that generate thousands of requests per minute, and others that are hundreds per *day*), we like the option of having the ability to scale them independently through ReplicaSets on the deployments.

However, I have some concerns regarding upper limits of how many deployments can exist/be successfully managed within a cluster, as we’d be looking at potentially hundreds of different clients, which will continue to grow. I also have concerns of costs, and how having dedicated resources (essentially an entire VM) for our smaller clients might impact our budgets.

So my questions are:

- is this a good idea at all? Why or why not, and if not, are there alternative architectures we could look at to achieve the same thing?
- is this solution more expensive than it needs to be?

I’d appreciate any insights you could offer, thank you!

Comment: How many clients do you have/expect to have?  If you have 1,000 clients, and 90% of them are in that long-tail "hundreds of requests per day" range, and each replica requires 4 GB of RAM, then you'd be paying for 4 TB of RAM to mostly sit idle.  That many pods would also put some stress on the Kubernetes core.

Comment: We haven't done a deep-dive yet as we're still exploring, but the number of very-high usage clients is probably less than a dozen. The other few hundred are probably the much smaller size. There isn't a lot of middle.

If isolating the smaller clients is generally very resource-inefficient, is there a reasonable middle-ground that can play nicely together with full-on isolation of the larger clients?

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/images/enterprise-multitenancy.svg

Comment: @Hackerman just so I'm understanding this properly: is this topology saying that each tenant would have their own namespace? Is the expectation here also that these are the same application, running for four different clients?

I'm also not sure I fully understand why the clients would interact with the control plane themselves. I would expect them to interact with the application, and the application would interact with the control plane as needed.

Comment: Short answer, yes :) . There is a lot of documentation about "K8s Multitenancy Namespaces"

Comment: Could you share some of that documentation for me to read through?

Comment: @Chewy because namespaces are described to be used as a way to divide cluster resources between multiple users (or teams) which actively makes use of the cluster themself. For example, user A can interact only with namespace A and with a ResourceQuota which limits the amount of resources usable on that namespace. What I mean is that, if you provide the infrastructure.. but the applications are provided by the users, then you definitely need to go with namespaces because they can easily be isolated from each other. If you also provide the applications, then you may or may not use namespaces.

Comment: It's definitely _our_ application running inside the Cluster. We're looking at different technologies we can leverage to help with tenancy.  In this case, I don't think namespaces would be helpful, unless I'm mistaken.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of a couple options for this situations:

1. Deploying separate clusters for each customer. This also allows you to size your clusters properly for each customers and configure autoscaling accordingly for each of them. The drawback is that each cluster has a management fee of 0.10$ per hour, but you get full guarantee that everything is isolated, and you can use the [cluster autoscaler](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/cluster-autoscaler) to make sure that only the VMs that are actually needed for each customer are running. For smaller customers, you may wanna use this with small (and cheap) machine types.
2. Another option would be to, as mentioned in the comments, use namespaces. However you would have to [configure the cluster properly](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/securing-a-cluster/#controlling-the-capabilities-of-a-workload-or-user-at-runtime) as there [exist ways of accessing services in different namespaces](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#services-without-selectors).
3. Implement customer isolation in your own software running on a cluster. This would imply forcing your software to access only the database for a given customer, but I would not recommend to go this route.

Comment: Can you provide suggestions as to why you don't like number 3? I've engaged with nearly a dozen different people in various places, and they all thus been of the opposite reaction -- that the tenancy should be managed from within the application, and not in Kubernetes.

Can you explain why your position is different?

Comment: Hi,
This is my opinion because custom code is subjected to bugs and possible exploits that might take a lot of time to be found out, especially if your code is not open source.
If you have a team in your company (or, even better, an external company) that can do a security audit on the code to make sure there aren't any possible security flaws, then it's a perfectly viable option, however keep in mind that even security audits are not perfect and they might miss something, and that new security issues could be introduced with each new code patch, TLDR it's alright but you need to be careful.